# What are the capitalization rules for words placed in the argument of the \hyphenation command?

Tags: hyphenation

I understand that the `\hyphenation` command is case-sensitive when it comes to the words placed in its argument. For example, the command `\hyphenation{SU-MA-TRA}` will affect the words "SUMATRA", "Sumatra", and "sumatra", while the command `\hyphenation{Su-ma-tra}` will only affect the words "Sumatra" and "sumatra". In general, which case-variants of a given word are affected by a given case-variant of a word provided in the argument to the `\hyphenation` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compile the following with `tex`:

```
\hyphenation{kop-fw-poj-a-ww-hjr-eltr}

\showhyphens{kopfwpojawwhjreltr}
\showhyphens{KOPFWPOJAWWHJRELTR}
\showhyphens{Kopfwpojawwhjreltr}
\bye
```

(but any engine will do). The console will show

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 3--3
[] \tenrm kop-fw-poj-a-ww-hjr-eltr

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4--4
[] \tenrm KOP-FW-POJ-A-WW-HJR-ELTR

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 5--5
[] \tenrm Kop-fw-poj-a-ww-hjr-eltr
```

proving that the capitalization of the words in the document is irrelevant.

Now try

```
\hyphenation{KoP-fw-pOJ-a-WW-hjr-eltr}

\showhyphens{kopfwpojawwhjreltr}
\showhyphens{KOPFWPOJAWWHJRELTR}
\showhyphens{Kopfwpojawwhjreltr}
\bye
```

and the console output will be exactly the same.

Unless you play nasty things with `\lccode`, there is no difference whether you capitalize the words in the `\hyphenation` list.